# intent-filter for a service : using a custom mime type

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want to add a custom mime so that my  Android Service or a BroadcastReceiver would detect my custom files.
I have seen answers to questions like [How to add custom mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744944/how-to-add-custom-mime-type) and [How to add custom mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744944/how-to-add-custom-mime-type)

The answers here are shown for an Activity. But what modifications are required for service or BroadcastReceiver?  I tried the same code for them, but it did not work.
I am new to android development. Some nice and detailed explanation is welcome. Is it possible?
Where am I going wrong.

The code that I used is :

```
   <service android:name="XcardReceivedService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">


           <intent-filter>
                    <!--   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    -->
                    <data android:scheme="file" />
                    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.Xcard" />
                    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>


      </service>
```

Comment: You pretty much never use MIME types with services or broadcast receivers. Could you explain, completely, what you mean by "detect my custom files"?

Comment: I am extremely new to android. I have a file created on my sdcard by name "card.Xcard" . I want to start an activity when the user clicks on that file. but before the activity is started I want to add the data from that file to the database. for that purpose I wanted to write a service or a broadcast receiver.

Comment: and I want to show the details in the activity of the data added to the database. Is there any other possible way? can implement it in this manner: Suppose i have activity A which displays the data in database. It can be started by an intent from other activity or when a user clicks on file of type ".Xcard". but , then how should i differentiate between "how the activity was started" whether from other activity or when user clicked on this file.

Comment: because when the activity A starts from other activity , it just has to fetch data from database and display, but when it has to start when user clicks on file , it first has to update the database and then display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but before the activity is started I want to add the data from that file to the database

You have to do that in the activity.

> or that purpose I wanted to write a service or a broadcast receiver.

Files do not open in to a service or a broadcast receiver.

> Is there any other possible way?

Put your code into your activity.

> how should i differentiate between "how the activity was started" whether from other activity or when user clicked on this file.

Examine the `Intent` that was used to start your activity. You get this `Intent` via `getIntent()`. You can call `getData()` on the `Intent` to get the `Uri` associated with it. If this is not `null`, it should be the path to your file.

Comment: thankyou sir!!!! I am privileged to have you answer my question. I will try your suggestion. I need some more of your favour. can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441330/declaring-mime-type-for-a-custom-file-that-is-to-be-sent-via-bluetooth