# Android7ff: How to register a new mimetype for a new file extension that can be used by every Android-filemanager?

Tags: android, mime-types, file-manager

I want to open my own fileformat with the file extsion ".poi" [with my own app](https://github.com/k3b/LocationMapViewer) from any filemanager.

When i open "myfile.kml" in [Simple-File-Manager](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-File-Manager) the filemanager triggers: View with "content://media/external/file/12345" and mimetype "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml".

I am looking for a way to tell every filemanager that "myfile.poi" correspond to mime "application/poi+xml"

---

More technical background. In the android manifest you can declare in AndroidManifest.xml what your app wants to receive.

To receive ".kml" files you can use

```
   <intent-filter>..<data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
```

In old android versions you can use filename filters

```
        <data android:host="*"
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.poi"
            android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:host="*"
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:pathPattern=".*\\.kml"
            android:scheme="file" />
```

However. **In more recent Android versions "files" cannot be used anymore**

---

Before consindering to close this question as a duplicate:
[similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+register+mime)
are outdated because in Android7 and later "file" cannot be used any more

example: [How to add custom mime type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744944/how-to-add-custom-mime-type) asked 10 years ago