# Multiple file extension/mimetype intent-filters with one activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

Gents,

I'm trying to get it so that my Android application can respond both to files being opened (via matching their extensions) and to mime-types (so they will work from the browser).

I've followed the advice here:

[Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

but still had no luck.

The relevant section from my android manifest file is as follows:

```
<activity android:name="MuPDFActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

As you can see, I would like the app to be invoked for .pdf, .xps, and .cbz files, also files with the relevant mimetypes. Local tests here seem to suggest that the .pdf and application/pdf sections are both working, but try as I might, the .xps (and presumably .cbz) sections are not.

Am I missing something obvious here? Can each Activity only have one mimetype/file pattern?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Robin

Comment: Which Android Version? I noted that there are differences here. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650378/how-did-intent-filter-change-from-android-2-to-android-4

Answer (score 4):

afaik, that would rather be like that (one filter with the various values):

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Also, is it possible that the mime-type is incorrect?

Comment: Interesting. I once tried to combine `android:mimeType` and `android:pathPattern` and that did not work.

Comment: For `android:pathPattern` all four attributes of the `<data>` tag need to be set in Android 4. So your hint won't help the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple `<data>` are logical OR and treated separately. So you have one tag with `android:scheme` but without `android:pathPattern` and one with `android:pathPattern` but without a `android:host` and so on. So none of the `<data>` tags are complete and will do any good.

You should use:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
          android:scheme="file"
          android:mimeType="*/*"
          android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz"
          android:host="*"
        ></data>
    </intent-filter>
```

You can have a second `<data>` but it would need all four attributes again as all four attributes are mandatory with Android 4 if you want to use `android:pathPattern`. (They weren't with older Android versions)

Comment: Hi Martin if i use the above intent filter, My app is showing when i tried to open gmail app from notification.

Comment: Combining multiple **<data>** tags works?  It only detects the first one for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Can each Activity only have one mimetype/file pattern?

No. By your own admission, two are working (PDF x 2).

> Am I missing something obvious here?

I doubt that the `BROWSABLE` element will do you much good on the ones you have it on, and you need it for the others. `BROWSABLE` is for browsers, which will go down the MIME type path.