# Start a phonegap/cordova app with command line argument?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app that's all about processing a certain type of file. I would like to wire it up so that you can double click on any file with a given extension and it will open using my app.

To the best of my knowledge this involves wiring up the os to respond to files of that extension by starting my app passing the path to the file via a commandline argument.  The last part is where I'm stuck. How do I read any commandline arguments passed into my phonegap application?

Answer (score 1):

This SO answer will give you an idea of how to register your Android app to open up based on mimeType or file extension.

[Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still missing the part where cordova/phonegap then reads it. What API do I use to access it?