# associate usb barcode scanner input exclusively with my app

Tags: android, usb, barcode

I have an app that reads barcode input from a scanner. The scanner is treated as a keyboard (as usual) and I get the scanned input while my app has focus. However durting periods of inactivity my app is killed and then misses any input that may occur.

Since the scanner is a usb device it should be possible to associate it exclusively with my app. I have a usb printer and that is associated with my app by default. So the OS starts my app (if needed) on the USB_ATTACH event of the printer.

How do I get the scanner to be associated by default with my app and ensure  my app gets any input from the scanner?

Comment: Perhaps this would help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension

Comment: That refers to a file type. In this case it is a usb device and additionally detected by default as a keyboard -which automatically means available to all apps