# Android - Open file with specific app (Not default)

Tags: android

What I have so far is an async task that downloads a file, which then I want to open the file with another app called Blocklauncher, which then lets you import the file into Blocklauncher. Blocklauncher has this ability built into, as seen in apps such as Mods for Pocket Edition, so I'm trying to do the same. I was hoping to simply use an intent that sends the user to the app, but I haven't seen any posts like mine, so I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: You can use the intent filter ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension