# Android: Associate app with custom file type

Tags: android, file-association

I've got a file type, the extension is '.rfts' (really it's just storing a JSON string that represents user configurations for an audio amplifier). I'd like to be able to open this file when it's an attachment from an e-mail (Gmail for example) so I can import user settings from another tablet.

Here's what my manifest looks like (note that I didn't include the other activities in this, but there's 4 others that don't have intent filters).

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/RFtheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>

            <data android:pathPattern="\\.rfts$"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name=".model.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.rockfordcorp.app3sixty.provider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </provider>
</application>
```

I've been trying several other suggested fixes from other questions, but they were for things like opening a pdf from a browser.

When I try to open a .rfts attachment in Gmail, it tells me *"You don't have an app that can open this file (.rfts). Try searching google play for one that can"*

I'm at a loss as to what I need to be doing here. I don't have any idea what mime Gmail would be using to open a .rfts, nor what scheme it would be using. I've tried a few different combinations but nothings really worked. I just haven't put in the magic combination of category, mimetype, pattern and scheme that Android is looking for to associate this file to my app.

**EDIT** *some success, but not quite there yet*.

The questions suggested as fixes are off the mark, and the reason is because the scheme required is actually 'content', not 'file'

The intent filter that works is

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.rfts"/>
            <data android:scheme="content" android:pathPattern=".*\\.rfts" android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <!-- <data android:host="*"/> -->
        </intent-filter>
```

Without the *android:sceheme="content"* it does not work.

However, a new problem arises. Gmail now opens **all file types** that are not previously associated with another app. For example, if I were to try to open a *.rfff* file, it uses my app. If you try to open a *.txt* it opens a chooser for Chrome or HTML viewer.

This is close, but it opening other file types is problematic. Android:pathPattern evidently has no effect on what filetype my app is associated with.

**As this question was marked as a possible duplicate** I want to point out the solution suggested is not working for opening a file from g-mail not web, nor does it cover opening a **custom** filetype. Using that 'solution' with the file type swapped out causes g-mail to continue to insist there is no app on the device capable of opening the file type.

A different solution likely needs to be provided to associate opening this custom filetype via the intent from Gmail.

Comment: I believe the answer this question will put you on the right path:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)

Comment: Note that the question you suggest is a duplicate is for opening from the net, while mine is for opening from gmail. The solution to that question did **not** work for this.

Comment: Also note that I'm not opening an established file type from a browser. It turns out a different solution entirely is required for associating the app with filetypes to be opened via gmail. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: hey @MagicMarbles i am also stucked in same problem.Please tell me if you got any solution?

Comment: Afraid not, Android kept associating all sorts of file types with my app, so I ditched that and went another direction instead.

Answer (score 5):

## Update 2020

Android has moved towards content URIs and MIME-Types for intent filters.

### The Problem

A content URI does not necessarily have to contain the file's extension or name and it will be different between different applications that are providing the content/file.

Here are some example content URIs from different email applications for the **same** email attachment:

Gmail -> `content://com.google.android.gm.sapi/some_email@gmail.com/message_attachment_external/%23thread-a%3Ar332738858767305663/%23msg-a%3Ar-5439466788231005876/0.1?account_type=com.google&mimeType=application%2Foctet-stream&rendition=1`

Outlook -> `content://com.microsoft.office.outlook.fileprovider/outlookfile/data/data/com.microsoft.office.outlook/cache/file-download/file--2146063402/filename.customextention`

Samsung Email App -> `content://com.samsung.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/1/RAW`

As can see they are all different and are not guaranteed to contain anything related to your actual file. Thus, you cannot use the `android:pathPattern` like most have suggested.

### A work around solution for email attachments

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>

    <!--  Required for Gmail and Samsung Email App  -->
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>

    <!--  Required for Outlook  -->
    <data android:mimeType="application/my-custom-extension"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Through testing I found the MIME-Types that Gmail, Outlook, and Samsung Email used and added those to my intent-filter.

### Caveats/Gotchas

- I found that with my above solution, if I opened any file that was a binary type, it would automatically launch my app. I handled this in my activity by displaying a failed state if we could not parse the file. I figured this was a pretty rare event so it would acceptable.
- I could not find any way to launch my app via the file browser without adding `<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>` to my intent-filter. I couldn't use this because it would then launch my app whenever the user clicked **any** file on their phone (not just the custom-file-extension ones). I would not recommend adding this to your intent-filter.
- I had no luck using `android:scheme="file"` at all.
- I tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S10 on Android 10

### Final Thoughts

- There is currently no elegant solution for associating your app with a specific extension type in Android. This was the best that I could do in my situation.