# How to set my app to open zip files when opened from another apps?

Tags: java, android

I am new to this site so sorry if I posted in the wrong place.
My question is simple, How can I set my app to open specific file types. For example, When someone clicks on a zip file in any other app I want my app to be in the list of apps that are able to open this type.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this by adding a `<intent-filter>` to your application in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

pathPattern is where you specify what extension you want to match.

**Reference & thanks to** Brian Pellin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062112/6514945) here.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an IntentFilter like this one in your Manifest to your desired Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.zip" android:mimeType="*/*"  />
</intent-filter>
```

Read [more about Intent and IntentFilter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters).

You can customize some values, such as `host` and `pathPattern` as desired.

You can get information about the file provided by another Application through in your Activity, via `getIntent()`. Read the content of the Intent to get more info about the file.